# Rolling months data by year_month in obiee

Tags: sql, oracle, obiee

I just need to how to create Rolling months in Obiee. If I click for jan 2017,it should show datas from feb 2016.For past previous 12 Months it should show.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take few moments to take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to get better answers for your questions

Answer (score 0):

You will need a properly configured time dimension. As soon as you have that all the time series functionalities are at your disposal and will work immediately.
https://gerardnico.com/wiki/dat/obiee/obis/time_dimension
https://gerardnico.com/wiki/dat/obiee/obis/logical_sql/function_time

Comment: Time_dimemson are made correct but Still Column formula Showing Many Errors.Can You Suggest Any Formulas.My format is like jan-2017.

Comment: "Time_dimemson are made correct" <-- Really? Prove it.
"Still Column formula Showing Many Errors" <-- What errors?
http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html